# harddrive not opening

Tags: dual-boot, mount

i am new to Linux,i have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.Problem is when i boot into Ubuntu,my hard drives are not opening...it shows an error messege.
*I have already done a disk check from windows everything is fine.The error shown is-

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/rajnish/EC8A6A388A69FF86: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/rajnish/EC8A6A388A69FF86"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

And this is what i get on executing the command sudo fdisk -l
yeah i know that..i always shutdown windows before logging into ubuntu.
How to mount them in ubuntu?
and this is what i get after executing the command sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3efa4f7b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   204802047   102041600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       512002048   976771071   232384512    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       204804094   512002047   153598977    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       204804096   302458879    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       302460928   496001023    96770048   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       496003072   512002047     7999488   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Please help,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I believe is to shut windows down then you can mount the drive from ubuntu. You can not have windows suspended or in hibernation that is dangerous to do while booting ubuntu.

Fast startup needs to be disabled or windows 8 will actually enter a state of hibernation when you press the shutdown button instead of shutting down.

Comment: yeah i know that..i always shutdown windows before logging into ubuntu.
How to mount them in ubuntu?

Comment: This says "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)" that is not the case?

Comment: This is what i don't understand why it is showing this...i **shutdown** my laptop then after few moments i start it again and then boot into Ubuntu.
should i also turn off fast boot in windows?

Comment: Have you disabled fast startup? it needs to be disabled or or windows 8 will actually enter a state of hibernation when you press the shutdown button.

Comment: Yeah! :D it worked..
thanks a ton Wild Man for your help...appreciated. :)